# How to break down tuple from Python to PHP

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

I'm using HTTP post request from Codeigniter to python and return a tuple from MySQL to python

Codeigniter controller:

```
$data['email'] = $this->input->post("email");
$url = 'http://domain/path';
$data = array('email' => $data['email']);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Python code:

```
elif self.path=="/forgotpass":
    print "forgot password module"
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile, 
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
        })
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://domain")
    self.end_headers()
    #print form['email'].value
    email = str(form["email"].value)
    sql = "SELECT email_address, personal_id from personal_info where email_address='"+email+"'"
    result = validate(sql)
    print result
    #print email;
    self.wfile.write(result)


def validate(sql):
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","schema" )
        cnn = db.cursor()
        cnn.execute(sql)
        return cnn.fetchone()

        cnn.close()     
    except MySQLdb, e:
        print "Error validate function"
```

The display is, I think this is now a string format.

```
string(36) "('jerahmeel.acebuche@smsgt.com', 2L)"
```

In a simple Codeigniter connecting to a model.

The result of an array from mysql is:

array (column => value) etc etc..

You could display that array using foreach and $item->data;

But this result came from python which is a tuple and returning it to PHP is a different approach.

How will I break this tuple in PHP? or should I break it on python and return it to PHP?

Comment: You're printing the result of a call to `validate()`. What does that function do? You should probably post that code.

Comment: transfer data between servers with a common data format, say `json`, `xml` etc. Otherwise you need to parse it (receiver side), or send (sender side) it in some format so that the receiver understands.

Comment: Instead of focusing on the particular data structure(format) `tuple`, lets start communicating with common data format as suggested by @mshsayem. In my opinion [phpserialize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize) would be very useful package in this case.

Comment: @DanielRoseman . here it is . I've updated my post .

Comment: @mshsayem . you mean like  pseudo code (self.wfile.write(jsonify(result)).. like this? sorry . i dont have any idea about json . hehe.